# CURL: ftp-skip-pasv-ip using PHP

Tags: php, curl

I can't find any option like `--ftp-skip-pasv-ip` when I use cURL extension for PHP (with `curl_setopt` command).

Is there any equivalence for `--ftp-skip-pasv-ip` in PHP cURL extension ? (I don't wan't to use `exec` command, I want to use the extension) I can't find the answer in PHP Manual (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Ok, so : `print_r(get_defined_constants(true)['curl']);` gives all curl const options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
curl_setopt ( $ch , CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1 );
```